# Display fields in one row + PHP

Tags: php, sql

Good Day, I want to display the value in my DB in one row. But what is happening now, it is being displayed horizontally

[Image Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Vaa.png)

```html
      <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;"class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th class="tblHeader">MODEL</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 1</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 2</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 3</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 4</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 5</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 6</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 7</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 8</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 9</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 10</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 11</th>
      <th class="tblHeader">PERIOD 12</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
 <?php      
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hh_bpm");                          
$query = "SELECT  *
FROM bpm_periods_instance
WHERE  Category_Name=1
";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 { ?>
  <tbody style="font-size:20px; text-align:center;">
    <tr>

     <td><?php echo $row["Text_Value"];?></td>

    </tr> 
<?php }  mysqli_close($connect);?> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to display the string value in line with Period 1 - 12`

I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: You would need 12 td's in that case per row

Comment: If your database connection is on the actual page and that page there is not included or required from a secure folder you have a very serious security issue. Oh, you probably want to use [$mysqli_result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, move your while loop just before the `<tr>`, for you want to have just one table body. Then it's better to have the same number of `<th>`s and `<td>`s. I see you have 12 `<th>`s, so make 12 `<td>`s in each `<tr>` (leave them empty if you want, but include them)

Answer (score 1):

The  tags is a row containing  headings for your table. For your to Match your column names you must have equal number of  as th in your table.

```
 <tr>
     <th>heading1</th>
     <th>heading2</th>
     <th>heading3</th>
 </tr>
```

You can now iterate this for your rows.

```
 <tr> 
   <td>data1</td>
   <td>data2</td>
   <td>data3</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are showing just a singe TD for each row.

What you are missing is a row loop:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 { ?>
  <tbody style="font-size:20px; text-align:center;">
    <tr>

    <?php 
      foreach($row as $k=>$v)
        echo "<td>$v</td>";
    ?>


    </tr> 
<?php }  mysqli_close($connect);?> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you should output TDs for all columns manually:

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["Column1"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Column2"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Column3"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Column4"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Column5"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["Column6"];?></td>
...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a crosstab query to achieve the results that you want. Since there is very little information I'll just give and outline

```
SELECT info,
       sum( if(MONTH(dt)=1,1,0) as Period_1,
       sum( if(MONTH(dt)=2,1,0) as Period_2,
//--- repeat for all 12 months
```

Your query will return 13 columns (info and Period_1 to Period_12). You'll need to adjust the html to cater for this output.